# Console project created with dotnet generic host does not get user secrets for ef migrations

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, entity-framework-core

I've followed the guideline [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to create a console application with ef core support. It uses user secrets to store connection strings and runs correctly. However, when trying to run

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await CreateHostBuilder(args).RunConsoleAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);

        private static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext hostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionStrings = hostBuilderContext.Configuration
                .GetSection("ConnectionStrings")
                .Get<ConnectionStrings>();
            services.AddSingleton(new Config
            {
                ConnectionStrings = connectionStrings
            });
            services.AddDbContext<TargetDbContext>(options => 
                options.UseNpgsql(connectionStrings.TargetDb));
        }
    }

    public class Config
    {
        public ConnectionStrings ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConnectionStrings
    {
        public string AdminDb { get; set; }
        public string TenantTemplate { get; set; }
        public string TargetDb { get; set; }
    }
```

```sh
dotnet ef migrations add create_target_databse --context TargetDbContext
```

It cannot find user secrets and the connection strings object is null. What is wrong and how can I solve it?

P.S: I've had no trouble with asp.net core project template. I only face this problem in console.